# How can I force the AdminConsent using AuthenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync?

Tags: c#, multi-tenant, azure-active-directory

I have a native app which i'm using in a multi-tenant scenario.
To authenticate the user -- and to get their consent on allowing this application to access Azure on their behalf -- I simply instantiate an AuthenticationContext and call AcquireTokenAsync. However I don't know how if this by default uses the AdminConsent or not? If not how can i achieve that?

Below is the sample code that i use:

```
AuthenticationContext commonAuthContext = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common");
AuthenticationResult result = await commonAuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resource,
            clientId, replyUrl,
            new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Always));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this does not automatically invoke admin consent (even if an admin consents, they're just consenting for themselves, not for the whole tenant).

To invoke admin consent, you have to add `prompt=admin_consent` to the authentication request:

```
AuthenticationResult result = await commonAuthContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
    resource,
    clientId,
    replyUrl,
    new PlatformParameters(PromptBehavior.Auto), // <-- Important: use PromptBehavior.Auto
    UserIdentifier.AnyUser,
    "prompt=admin_consent"); // <-- This is the magic
```

Of course, you should not send all users to sign in with this, as it will fail if the user is not an admin.

See "Triggering the Azure AD consent framework at runtime": https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-integrating-applications/#triggering-the-azure-ad-consent-framework-at-runtime

Comment: Thanks so much Philippe!

Comment: We try to avoid the PromptBehavior.Auto. The reason is that it uses that was cached in the browser. If you have different IDs for different tenancies then you would not get a chance to change that. unless there's a way around that and I don't know it.

Comment: I suspect (though am not certain) that `prompt=admin_consent` will always prompt for re-auth (similar to `prompt=login`, which is the result of `PromptBehavior.Always`).